# Callback Url in Paytm Payment Gateway

Tags: java, android-studio, paytm

I have integrated Paytm Payment Gateway in my android app. But the callback url for production mode mentioned in their documentation isn't redirecting me to my app with the responses.
It just opens up a page showing redirecting to my app and then nothing happens and on pressing back button a dialog box pops up asking whether to cancel the transaction or not even if the transaction was successful.
The url mentioned in their documentation is given below and this isn't working. Is there some other callback url to be used so that it works?

```
https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=$orderid
```

The code used is:

```
     RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(UpiPayment.this);

            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.has("CHECKSUMHASH")){
                            String CHECKSUMHASH=jsonObject.getString("CHECKSUMHASH");

                            PaytmPGService paytmPGService=PaytmPGService.getProductionService();

                            HashMap<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                            paramMap.put( "MID" , mid);
                            paramMap.put( "ORDER_ID" , orderId);
                            paramMap.put( "CUST_ID" , customerId);
                            paramMap.put( "CHANNEL_ID" , "WAP");
                            paramMap.put( "TXN_AMOUNT" , amount);
                            paramMap.put( "WEBSITE" , "DEFAULT");
                            paramMap.put( "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" , "Retail");
                            paramMap.put( "CALLBACK_URL", callbackUrl);
                            paramMap.put("CHECKSUMHASH",CHECKSUMHASH);

                            PaytmOrder order=new PaytmOrder(paramMap);
                            paytmPGService.initialize(order,null);

                            paytmPGService.startPaymentTransaction(UpiPayment.this, true, true, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTransactionResponse(Bundle inResponse) {
                                    Toast.makeText(UpiPayment.this, "Payment Transaction response " + inResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    if(inResponse.getString("STATUS").equals("TXN_SUCCESS")){

                                        Toast.makeText(UpiPayment.this, "payment successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void networkNotAvailable() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network connection error: Check your internet connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String inErrorMessage) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed: Server error" + inErrorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UI Error " + inErrorMessage , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode, String inErrorMessage, String inFailingUrl) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load webpage " + inErrorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Transaction cancelled" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTransactionCancel(String inErrorMessage, Bundle inResponse) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load webpage " + inResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });



                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(UpiPayment.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    paramMap.put( "MID" , mid);
                    paramMap.put( "ORDER_ID" , orderId);
                    paramMap.put( "CUST_ID" , customerId);
                    paramMap.put( "CHANNEL_ID" , "WAP");
                    paramMap.put( "TXN_AMOUNT" , amount);
                    paramMap.put( "WEBSITE" , "DEFAULT");
                    paramMap.put( "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" , "Retail");
                    paramMap.put( "CALLBACK_URL", callbackUrl);

                    return paramMap;

                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Can you share your `Volley` code?

Comment: @codebod I have attached the code now.

Comment: Have you got any solutions? I am also facing similar issue. I have used Custom Callback url. On successful payment Callback url called but In My app page is not redirecting and on back press I am getting popup for cancel transaction.

Comment: No, not yet @Nik.. actually I integrated upi payment gateway instead of paytm after searching for solutions for few days.